# Position div on top of a html canvas with fluid layout

Tags: css, html5-canvas, fluid-layout

I am playing with my first fluid layout, I have a html canvas which i can place items on top of using absolute positioning, however as soon as i do this, it looses it's fluid ability to alter depending on browsers viewing the page.  Is it possible to position on top of a canvas without loosing the ability to use the fluid layout aspect.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us some code? It's pretty difficult to find the problem without seeing the code.

Comment: here's the page, you can see the logo image and menu text sit below the canvas.  http://http://www.redstardigitalmedia.co.uk/cm2/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't open the URL you listed, but if I understand your question correctly, you can get an absolutely positioned box to adjust to the viewport's width by setting both it's left and right coordinates. Example:

```
#box {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:20px;
  right:20px;
}
```